# Bootstrap and AngularJS: Modal confirmation deleting first row

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I got a `table` which repeats a `delete` `button` for each and every member. The confirmation `button` does work when I don't use the `modal`, however if i use the `Modal`, the first row only gets deleted. 
As I researched, it could be that since the `delete` is getting repeated, its `value` stays for the first row.

Table HTML Code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="customForms" ng-show="showMembers">
    <thead><tr> <th> ID </th> <th>Name</th> <th>Surname</th> <th>Date Of Affiliation</th> <th>Status</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Summary</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
            <td>{{member.memberID}}</td>
            <td>{{member.name}}</td> 
            <td>{{member.surname}}</td>
            <td>{{member.dateOfAffiliation}}</td>
            <td>{{member.status}}</td>
            <td>{{member.email}}</td>
            <td>{{member.summary}}</td>

            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> DELETE </button>
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            Are you sure you wish to delete this row? 
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteMember(member)" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>      
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

AngularJS Code:

```
$scope.deleteMember = function(member) {        
        $http.post('model/deleteMember.php', member).success(function(data) {
        $scope.getMember();
        });
}
```

Comment: According to your code, when you delete using the modal, you pass the correct parameter to the controller by invoking `ng-click="deleteMember(member)"`

Whichever component you use to delete the member, you need to pass the model that needs to be delete. You can just use `ng-click="deleteMember(member)"` to trigger the delete action.

Comment: @Jodevan can you kindly rephrase please? I have put the `ng-click="deleteMember(member)` on the `button` which is suppose to delete the row.

Comment: You know what? Can you provide an example in plunker.co?

Comment: @Jodevan Apologies for my huge delay! Please find my plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Njps8DZnJXfNjyOBD6JB?p=preview